# Why does the client use more ram with a different server?

Tags: c#, node.js, memory

I was doing some performance testing on NodeJS request count vs .Net Core, and  I found exactly what I was expecting. Obviously the request count of .Net Core was much higher. But, what I found particularly interesting is that the client, without recompiling the code, actually used more RAM via the NodeJS server vs the .Net Core server. The RAM usage differences were actually rather significant, where I observed spikes of a much higher nature with the NodeJS server than the .Net Core server.

Using .Net Core 2.0.0 and NodeJS 8.3.0

The flooder in question. With .Net Core server, the running uses anywhere from 480MB to 700MB at the worst of the usage. With the NodeJS server, it uses 700MB to 1.4GB of RAM on my PC (both of which max out the CPU).

[Flooder code](https://pastebin.com/aQge2UQd)

```
HttpServer.cs is the actual code that does the work
Source.cs is where the HttpServer is run in a separate task to allow Console.ReadLine separately.
```

[Git link to .Net Core server](https://github.com/jschmold/Http-Server-Experiment)

The NodeJS Server code

```
const http = require('http')

let serv = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.write("Hello!")
    // res.destroy() // Uncomment to reduce RAM usage, but the point is still valid
})

serv.listen(48435)
```

What would cause such a significant difference in RAM usage, and of all things, why would the client be the one receiving the punishment for it? I understand the server using more RAM, processor, or simply being slower, but why would the same code doing the same thing for the client use almost double the RAM in some cases?

Comment: Only thing I could think of is that with the node.js server, the client has more simultaneous connections at once.  Could also have to do with http version support in each server.  One may be running http/2.

Comment: You figure there'd be that many more connections? Tasks are multi-threaded in C#, and NodeJS uses 1 thread. The finished NodeJS request count is around 483k, and the C# server request count is around 780k

Comment: I'm just offering you some ideas to explore that could explain the difference.

Comment: I know, lol. I'm just thinking "aloud" back to you in case it sparks more ideas. I am greatly appreciated for the suggestions, by the way. Myself and the 4 friends I've talked to are all confused.

Comment: Just because node.js is single threaded does not mean that it can't have a zillion requests in play at the same time - it can.  It depends on what those requests do and how the server handles incoming TCP connections when there are more than it can handle.

Comment: That would make sense. The faster response of the .Net Core server could mean the client is disposing of the requests at a higher rate

Comment: Your "do nothing" server is not very representative of actual server scalability.  Put some real I/O operations in the server to make a more realistic comparison.  That happens to be where node.js shows its advantages too vs. threaded servers.

Comment: The interest was simply to see the general response time of 1 client to 1 server. I was curious to see if HTTP was sufficiently fast with C# to be in place of a raw socket, and the answer to my test was that it is more than fast enough. But, on a whim, I wanted to see if NodeJS performed better. I could just use clustering to see if it increases the request response rate.

Comment: @jfriend00 Just an update. Added clustering to the NodeJS code and the RAM usage dropped below the .Net Core code I made, and actually produced an output of 134,904 requests more, confirming that the client's "holding" of the requests is what is causing the RAM issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem was that the client, by nature, created an infinite amount of requests. The faster the server was able to respond to these requests, the quicker they were disposed of on the client side. As such, there was drastically less RAM usage after clustering Node's HTTP server.

Speed

NodeJS with clustering: 935k requests, lowest RAM 360MB, highest 680MB
.Net Core: 780k requests, lowest ram 580MB, highest 800MB
NodeJS no clustering: 435k requests, lowest RAM 800mb, highest 1.4GB

A thank you to jfriend00 that helped me figure out the real source. It's also a good indicator as to how "fast" the server is (at the extreme expense of RAM) to look at the RAM usage while it is processing.